# Autocomplete file name in strings?

Tags: python-jedi

I feel like this should be easy, but right now I have SuperTab (I can't install YouCompleteMe because I have vim with python3, not python2) and jedi-vim installed. Most jedi completions work well, but the following fails miserably:

```
file = './<tab>'
```

Autocompletes to:

```
file = '.self.
```

I honestly can't think of any reason a string containing '.self.' would be useful. Is this a bug, or is this a config error on my part?

Comment: What other plugins are you using? I've had similar issues (but the problem was not because of those two plugins).

Comment: I have way too many plugins (34), ones that may conflict: python-mode (but with almost all functions disabled, disabling it does not fix the issue), nercommenter, snipmate, ssessionmate, yntastic, taglist, airline, fugitive, latex-suite, matchit, pandoc-syntax, pathogen, vim-template, vimux, tmux-navigator. There are others too, but I think they are too different in functionality to interfere.

Comment: I figured it out, it was snipmate automatically taking the tab key. I changed the snipmate mapping and it now works fine. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: I was thinking it's probably snipmate (but I forgot that name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the plugin snipmate.

If you want to keep snipmate there's three options:

1. Remove the `self.` snippet from snipmate (you can configure it).
2. Replace snipmate with an other solution (e.g. ultisnips)
3. I have fixed this issue a long while ago by patching snipmate: https://github.com/davidhalter/vim-snipmate However it's very outdated and I'm not using snipmate anymore.

Comment: Also note that it can be fixed by changing the keybinding in the ``vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim``. You can manually replace the tab mappings with, for example ``imap <c-a> <esc>a<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`` and ``smap <c-a> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger``. Inelegant but it works.